# How to format submenu so that it stretches across the screen

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my menus formatted correctly. Currently the top menu submenu is vertical, and I'd prefer it look more like [gooddata.com](http://gooddata.com).

The site is [jobcreatr.com](http://jobcreatr.com), and I'm trying to make the skeleton of the site look something like gooddata.com.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<ul id="superfish-2" class="menu sf-menu sf-main-menu sf-horizontal sf-style-whiteshadow sf-total-items-3 sf-parent-items-1 sf-single-items-2 superfish-processed sf-js-enabled sf-shadow">
<li id="menu-1299-2" class="first odd sf-item-1 sf-depth-1 sf-no-children">
<a class="sf-depth-1" title="" href="http://jobcreatr.com/activity">Activity Feed</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-1300-2" class="middle even sf-item-2 sf-depth-1 sf-no-children">
<a class="sf-depth-1" title="" href="http://jobcreatr.com/course-categories">Course Categories</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-1301-2" class="last odd sf-item-3 sf-depth-1 sf-total-children-6 sf-parent-children-0 sf-single-children-6 menuparent">
<a class="sf-depth-1 menuparent sf-with-ul" title="" href="http://jobcreatr.com/products">
My Courses
<span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span>
</a>
<ul class="sf-hidden" style="float: none; width: 12.6429em; display: block;">
<li id="menu-2170-2" class="first odd sf-item-1 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children" style="white-space: normal; float: left; width: 100%;">
<a class="sf-depth-2" title="" href="/course-categories/business" style="float: none; width: auto;">Business</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-2171-2" class="middle even sf-item-2 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children" style="white-space: normal; float: left; width: 100%;">
<a class="sf-depth-2" title="" href="/course-categories/computers" style="float: none; width: auto;">Computers</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-2172-2" class="middle odd sf-item-3 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children" style="white-space: normal; float: left; width: 100%;">
<a class="sf-depth-2" title="" href="/course-categories/education" style="float: none; width: auto;">Education</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-2173-2" class="middle even sf-item-4 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children" style="white-space: normal; float: left; width: 100%;">
<a class="sf-depth-2" title="" href="/course-categories/health" style="float: none; width: auto;">Health & Fitness</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-2174-2" class="middle odd sf-item-5 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children" style="white-space: normal; float: left; width: 100%;">
<a class="sf-depth-2" title="" href="/course-categories/labor" style="float: none; width: auto;">Labor</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-2175-2" class="last even sf-item-6 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children" style="white-space: normal; float: left; width: 100%;">
<a class="sf-depth-2" title="" href="/course-categories/other" style="float: none; width: auto;">Other</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I've tried setting the CSS to inline on both the  tag as well as the

tag, but for some reason the menu always stays vertical.

Here's my CSS:

```
.sf-menu.sf-horizontal.sf-shadow ul, .sf-menu.sf-vertical.sf-shadow ul, .sf-menu.sf-navbar.sf-shadow ul ul {
width: 100% !important;
background-color: #F6F6F6;
background: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:22px;
    overflow: none;
}

.sf-menu.sf-horizontal.sf-shadow ul a, .sf-menu.sf-vertical.sf-shadow ul a, .sf-menu.sf-navbar.sf-shadow ul ul a {
/*width: 100%!important;*/
position: relative;
left: 0;
display: inline-block;
}

.sf-menu.sf-style-whiteshadow li {
overflow: visible;
}
```

What should be changed? Is something keeping the width small, so that it can't expand to the entire width of the page?

Comment: the first thing I notice is that you don't have any closing </li> tags - and nothing in your lists. Whats going on with that?

Comment: Ah, sorry, copying error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subnavigation `<ul class="sf-hidden">` is absolutely positioned relative to it's parent `<li>`.

In the superfish CSS it has:

```
.sf-menu li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 498;
}
```

You need to override that 'relative' positioning.  If you have access to that css file change `position: relative` to `position: static`.  If not, override it with a more specific selector:

```
.content .sf-menu li {
  position: static; 
}
```

Comment: This made each list item take up the full space, rather than only a portion of the full space. I want each item to only take up a portion of the full width.

Comment: Yeah so then you need to style the subnav li.  E.g. `display: inline-block; margin-left: 0;` etc but I thought that was beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working.

.sf-menu.sf-style-whiteshadow .sf-depth-2 {
    border-bottom: medium none;
    display: inline-block;
}

Comment: Problem is you have some inline styling coming from somewhere setting the width of the child `<li>` to 100% (it's also set in the CSS).  If you can't control that, you may need something like `.sf-menu.sf-style-whiteshadow .sf-depth-2 { width: auto !important; }`

Comment: Most of this stuff is probably coming from the superfish menu JS / CSS so you could always create your own navigation from scratch if the superfish is causing too much unwanted code.

Comment: It took me a while to get everything right, but you ultimately led me to the solution, so you get the answer.

Comment: Glad you got there and pleased to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

remove `position:relative` from li tags.

add `left:0;right:0` to ul

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how attached you are to all of those inline styles, but here is how I would make that navigation: This way you could have more control from your CSS without having all of those inline declarations ---

[Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/ffEP9/)

### HTML

```
<nav class="global-nav">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>
            Menu Item 01
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>Sub items 01</li>
                <li>Sub items 01</li>
                <li>Sub items 01</li>
                <li>Sub items 01</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            Menu Item 02
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>Sub items 02</li>
                <li>Sub items 02</li>
                <li>Sub items 02</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            Menu Item 03
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>Sub items 03</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            Menu Item 04
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>Sub items 04</li>
                <li>Sub items 04</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

### CSS

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.global-nav {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.global-nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

.global-nav li {
    padding: 0 1em;
}

.global-nav .menu {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.global-nav .menu > li {
    display: block;
    float: right;
}

.global-nav .menu > li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.global-nav .sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    background-color: lightgray;
    color: gray;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}

.global-nav .sub-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.global-nav .menu > li:hover .sub-menu {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
```